# how do I make changes to value in query

Tags: c#, linq

How do I change a value within a query such as this:

```
        return (from cust in entities.vw_WebCustomer
                where cust.CorporationId == token.CorporationId &&
                      cust.Branch == branch &&
                      cust.AccountNumber == accountnumber
                select new CustomerRequest
                         {
                           AccountId = cust.AccountId,
                           AccountNumber = cust.AccountNumber,
                           AreaCode = cust.AreaCode,
                           Branch = cust.Branch,
                           BudgetBalance = (decimal) cust.BudgetBalance,
                           BudgetRate = (decimal) cust.BudgetRate,
                           CareOf = cust.CareOf,
                           City = cust.City,
                           CurrentBalance = (decimal) cust.CurrentBalance,
                           CurrentTankPercentage = (decimal) cust.PercentFull, 
};
```

I want to check the value of CurrentTankPercentage to zero if the cust.PercentFull is less than zero.

Do I have to break it apart to make changes to it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simplest way is to use a conditional operator:

```
select new CustomerRequest
 {
   ...
   CurrentTankPercentage = (decimal) (cust.PercentFull < 0 ? 0 : cust.PercentFull) 
 };
```

Another way is to use [`Math.Max`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.max.aspx):

```
select new CustomerRequest
 {
   ...
   CurrentTankPercentage = (decimal) Math.Max(cust.PercentFull,0) 
 };
```

But I find that harder to read. I tend to mis-read that as "give `CurrentTankPercentage` a Maximum value of 0", which is the opposite of what it really does.

Comment: Conditional operator is a slightly better description.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich Agreed.  Updated.

Comment: I get this when I use math.max:  System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Decimal Max(System.Decimal, System.Decimal)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
CurrentTankPercentage = ((decimal)cust.PercentFull) < 0 ? 0 : ((decimal)cust.PercentFull)
```